# Why are SQL-Server UDFs so limited?

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) for `create function`:

`User-defined functions cannot be used to perform actions that modify the database state.`

My question is simply - **why**?

Yes, a UDF that modifies data may have potentially unwanted side-effects.
Yes, there is overhead involved if a UDF is called thousands of times.

But that is the whole point of design and testing - to ensure that such issues are ironed out before deployment. So why do DB vendors insist on imposing these artificial limitations on developers? What is the point of a language construct that can essentially only be used as a wrapper for `select` statements?

The reason for this question is as follows: I am writing a function to return a GUID for a certain unique integer ID. If a GUID is already allocated for that ID I simply return it; otherwise I want to generate a new GUID, store that into a table, and return the newly-generated GUID. (Yes, this sounds long-winded and possibly crazy, but when you're sending data to another dev company who believes their design was handed down by God and cannot be improved upon, it's easier just to smile and nod and do what they ask).

I know that I can use a stored procedure with an output parameter to achieve the same result, but then I have to declare a new variable just to hold the result of the sproc. Not only that, I then have to convert my simple `select` into a while loop that inserts into a temporary table, and call the sproc for every iteration of that loop.

Comment: If you need something to modify database state - why not just use a stored proc instead?? UDF are meant to do a quick computation, a lookup or something and return a single value - that's all they're intended for. They do that pretty well.

Comment: Because I want to do something like `select my_udf(my_variable) from my_table`, where `my_udf` either selects or creates the value it returns (as explained in my post). Using an sproc to achieve the same result makes the code about 10 times larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually best to think of the available tools as a spectrum, from Views, through UDFs, out to Stored Procedures. At the one end (Views) you have a lot of restrictions, but this means the optimizer can actually "see through" the code and make intelligent choices. At the other end (Stored Procedures), you've got lots of flexibility, but because you have such freedom, you lose some abilities (e.g. because you can return multiple result sets from a stored proc, you lose the ability to "compose" it as part of a larger query).

UDFs sit in a middle ground - you can do more than you can do in a view (multiple statements, for example), but you don't have as much flexibility as a stored proc. By giving up this freedom, it allows the outputs to be composed as part of a larger query. By not having side effects, you guarantee that, for example, it doesn't matter in which row order the UDF is applied in. If you could have side effects, the optimizer might have to give an ordering guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your issue, I think, but taking this from your comment:

> I want to do something like `select my_udf(my_variable) from my_table`, where `my_udf` either selects or creates the value it returns

So you want a `select` that (potentially) *modifies* data. Can you look at that sentence on its own and tell me that that reads perfectly OK? - I certainly can't.

Reading your description of what you actually need to do:

> I am writing a function to return a
>   GUID for a certain unique integer ID.
>   If a GUID is already allocated for
>   that ID I simply return it; otherwise
>   I want to generate a new GUID, store
>   that into a table, and return the
>   newly-generated GUID.
>
> I know that I can use a stored
>   procedure with an output parameter to
>   achieve the same result, but then I
>   have to declare a new variable just to
>   hold the result of the sproc. Not only
>   that, I then have to convert my simple
>   select into a while loop that inserts
>   into a temporary table, and call the
>   sproc for every iteration of that
>   loop.

from that last sentence it sounds like you have to process many rows at once, so how about a single `INSERT` that inserts the GUIDs for those IDs that don't already have them, followed by a single `SELECT` that returns all the GUIDs that (now) exist?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you cannot implement the solution you came up with, it may be an indication that your solution is not optimal.

Using a statement like this

```
INSERT INTO IntGuids(IntValue, GuidValue)
SELECT MyIntValues.IntValue, NEWID()
FROM MyIntValues
LEFT OUTER JOIN IntGuids ON MyIntValues.IntValue = IntGuids.IntValue
WHERE IntGuids.IntValue IS NULL
```

creates all the GUIDs you need to have in 1 statement. No need to SELECT+INSERT for every single value.